# How to calculate two-time scale variance?

Tags: volatility, forecasting, variance

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate two-time scale variance as I do not have a strong mathematical background. Suppose I want to calculate the TSRV at 5 min intervals. Do I calculate the RV at t = 0,5,10,15min...etc. Then shift the time interval and calculate RV at t = 1,6,11,16min, ....RV at t = 4,9,14,19...and finally take the average of the 5 RVs I have calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here are the exact steps to calculate TSRV](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=6DGUEw-AfbwC&pg=PA451&lpg=PA451&dq=tsrv%20variance&source=bl&ots=piI33OVWZe&sig=df8NwVwwYGjWpXdp7mxGgeH_D2U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AJsUUZvYCYrllAW84oGwBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tsrv%20variance&f=false).

I also like [this paper](http://www.princeton.edu/~yacine/liquidity.pdf).